# Solving a general ODE

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential, companion-matrices

$ \newcommand{\der}[1]{\frac{d^#1 u}{dx^#1}} $
I'm trying to solve
$$\der n =\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\alpha_k\der k +e^{-x}.$$
It can be transformed to an set of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
u_0'=u_1\\
u_1'=u_2\\
\vdots\\
u_{n-1}'= \sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\alpha_ku_k +e^{-x}
\end{cases}$$
And in matrix form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}u_0\\u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&\dots&0\\
0&0&1&\dots & 0\\
0&0&0&\ddots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\alpha_0&\alpha_1&\alpha_1&\dots&\alpha_{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_0\\u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\vdots\\e^{-x}\end{pmatrix}$$
Now, I can start by solving the homogenous form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}u_0\\u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&\dots&0\\
0&0&1&\dots & 0\\
0&0&0&\ddots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\alpha_0&\alpha_1&\alpha_1&\dots&\alpha_{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_0\\u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$$
I've got stuck here and haven't managed to diagnalize the matrix to exponentiate it.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix in the homogeneous differential equation given in your question is also referred to as companion matrix.
Some interesting properties (eigenvalues, eigenvectors, etc.) are summarized in '[The Companion Matrix and Its Properties. Brand, L., The American Mathematical Monthly, 6, 71, p. 629--634, 1964'](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2312322).
The eigenvalues of this matrix correspond to zeros of the polynomial
$$
f(\lambda)=\lambda^n - \alpha_{n-1} \lambda^{n-1} - \ldots - \alpha_1\lambda-\alpha_0.
$$

It is not fully clear from your question if you try to find an analytic solution or if you want to compute a numerical solution. I would not expect a analytic solution to be available in general. Considering numerical solutions, hump effects can occur for the exponential of the companion matrix which can result in numerical difficulties. E.g. for $f(\lambda)=(\lambda+w)^n$ with $w\gg 0$ the companion matrix with the respective choice of coefficients $\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{n-1}$ does have an eigenvalue $-w\ll 0$ with multiplicity $n$ but the $\mu$-norm of this matrix scales with $w^n$ (hump effects for short time steps).